# Push notifications in Xamarin.Android not working on device

Tags: android, push-notification, xamarin

Have a trouble: developing on Xamarin.Android and create push-notifications. They good work on android emulators, but not work on real devices. What could be the reason of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to start push notifications from class, it can be started only from activity.